# How to wait for an event to complete, before the program continue running in java

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, jfilechooser

I'm trying to get a path using the *JFileChooser*, and then continue the execution of the programm. At first, a frame appears and prompt the user to press a button. When the button pressed, a *JFileChooser* window appears so the user can choose the directory.

The problem is this: When the button pressed, the program does not wait for the user to choose directory, although the *JFileChooser* window appears. It proceeds to the next command and throws a NullPointerException. To figure out, I have added the *promtENTERKey* method, so the program stops and waits for the "ENTER" key to be pressed.

All good, but I don't want to press the "ENTER" key. I want the program to continue **after** the user chooses the directory, without press anything. I've checked similar questions but I could not make it. I'm new in java (of course I got a lot of help for my code). Any ideas?

My code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DirChooser extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JButton button;
    static JFileChooser chooser = null;

    public DirChooser() {
        button = new JButton("Select Directory");
        button.addActionListener (this);
        add(button);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        String path = getDir();

        // ... code ...

    }

    public static String getDir() {

        String dir = null;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        DirChooser panel = new DirChooser();
        frame.addWindowListener(
                new WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }

            );
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel,"Center");
        frame.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        promtENTERKey();  

        dir = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        frame.dispose();    
        return dir;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){

        return new Dimension(200, 100);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        chooser = new JFileChooser (); 
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory (new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle ("choose directory");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode (JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed (false); // disable the "All files" option.

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
            System.out.println ("\n" + "Directory has been selected");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No Selection ");
        }
    }

    public static void promtENTERKey() {

        System.out.println("\n" + "Select directory first and then press \"ENTER\" to continue...");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are just attempting to prompt for a filename, then there is no need for the JFrame. All you need to do is display the JFileChooser. The JFileChooser is displayed in a modal JDialog which will stop execution until the file chooser is closed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I need the JFrame. This class is a part from a whole project I'm working on and a message, for the user, to choose directory is mandatory. I want to find a way to not press the ENTER key.

Comment: If the message is needed then you should be using a JOptionPane to display the message, not the command line.

Comment: Well, this is not exactly the code as is in my project. There is no main method in this class. The getDir method is called from another class. I also added the print command for confirmation that the code works properly. I'll study the JOptrionPane class, but I'm afraid that I have to make many changes to the code. Thank you!

Comment: "_this is not exactly the code as is in my project_" that if fine, but the code should represent the problem you are trying to solve. If it does not, please [edit]  and post  [mre].See this [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemoProject/src/components/FileChooserDemo.java) of using a `JFileChooser`.

Comment: I've edited the code. In "main" method, after the "getDir()" method's calling, some code follows. As for the problem, I think it's clear: As I said above, I don't want to press the "ENTER" key. I want to find a way, the program continues after the user chooses the directory, without press anything (without calling the "promptENTERKey()" method).

Comment: Tip: if you want to address a comment to a certain user add @+username (for example @c0der) to your message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, I think the next action should be started from your action listener. To fit in the framework you're proposing, we can make a countdown latch to block on instead of using a Scanner.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    //code to choose file.
    latch.countDown();
}
```

Now you can replace youre getEnter with

```
latch.await();
```

Comment: I believe the button press as well as the the new (modal) `JFileChooser` are all on the same thread (EDT) so I can't see why a latch is needed.

Comment: @c0der They start off on the main there, which is where they are using the  Scanner to read a line in. So there are two threads, the EDT and main thread.

Comment: @matt Yes, it worked. I added the "CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);" as a class variable (static) and replaced the "promtENTERKey();" command with "latch.await();". In the actionPerfomed() method I added a "latch.countDown();", as you proposed. Now it waits the user to choose directory.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrate what you are trying to achieve ?

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DirChooser {

    private static String path;

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Select Directory");
        button.addActionListener (e-> {
            path = getDir();
            System.out.println ("File chooser returned Path: " + path);
        });

        frame.add(button);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static String getDir() {

       JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser ();
       chooser.setCurrentDirectory (new java.io.File("."));
       chooser.setDialogTitle ("choose directory");
       chooser.setFileSelectionMode (JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
       chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed (false); // disable the "All files" option.
       int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
       if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
           return chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: No! It's not working. It behaves exactly as my code does. The command: "System.out.println ("File chooser returned Path: " + path);" does not wait for you to choose a path. It is been executed before.

Comment: Sorry, made a small mistake. Fixed it now/