# Wait for event to finish within another event

Tags: java, swing, events

I have a JTable where one of the cell is a LocalDate which I can update by clicking on it and it opens a date picker. The problem is that the modification is not taken into account because the date picker event waits for an input from the user but does not block. And so the event that handles the edit ends before it receives the edit.

I've checked this issue : [How to wait for an event to complete, before the program continue running in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009189/how-to-wait-for-an-event-to-complete-before-the-program-continue-running-in-jav) and tried to block event child with CountDownLatch but it freezes the app. I'm not sure but I guess it is something about event blocking within another event that causes trouble.

Here's some code to test :

For editing the cell :

```
package com.swing.datepicker;

import com.github.lgooddatepicker.components.DatePicker;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DateOfBirthCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, ActionListener {

private LocalDate curValue;
private final JButton button;

public DateOfBirthCellEditor() {
    button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.setDate(curValue);
    button.add(datePicker);

    datePicker.openPopup();

    datePicker.addDateChangeListener(dateChangeEvent -> {
        curValue = dateChangeEvent.getNewDate();
        System.out.println("should happens before - curValue : " + curValue);
    });

    System.out.println("should happens after - curValue : " + curValue);
    button.remove(datePicker);
    fireEditingStopped();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    curValue = (LocalDate) value;
    return button;
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return curValue;
}
}
```

main class :

```
package com.swing.datepicker;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

public class TableTest extends JFrame {

public TableTest() throws Exception {
    super("TEST");
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    initUI();
}

static class Dude {
    String name;
    LocalDate dateofbirth;

    public Dude(String name, LocalDate dateofbirth) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateofbirth = dateofbirth;
    }
}

public void initUI() {
    // Initial Settings
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600, 400);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();

    TableModel tableModel = new TableModel() {

        final List<Dude> data = List.of(new Dude("John", LocalDate.of(1998, 6,30)));
        final String[] headers = {"name", "date of birth"};

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return headers.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return headers[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 1) {
                return LocalDate.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0 -> data.get(rowIndex).name;
                case 1 -> data.get(rowIndex).dateofbirth;
                default -> null;
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (aValue != null) {
                switch (columnIndex) {
                    case 0 -> data.get(rowIndex).name = (String) aValue;
                    case 1 -> data.get(rowIndex).dateofbirth = (LocalDate) aValue;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {}

        @Override
        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {}
    };

    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    table.setDefaultEditor(LocalDate.class, new DateOfBirthCellEditor());

    JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
    tablePanel.add(table);

    contentPane.add(tablePanel);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TableTest window = new TableTest();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I used that date picker in other parts of my code, that's why I wanna keep it and do some weird code in editing the cell. I have this in my pom :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.lgooddatepicker</groupId>
    <artifactId>LGoodDatePicker</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sooo, you have a problem, the component library you're using isn't using a modal dialog, so you can't "wait" until it's done, but what you could try, is triggering `fireEditingStopped` in the `DateChangeListener`

Comment: I took a quick look at the repo / doc of the component you are using. It seems like there is a specific `DateTableEditor` available (`com.github.lgooddatepicker.tableeditors.DateTableEditor`), so you wouldn't have to do this yourself. There is also a [demo](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/blob/master/Project/src/main/java/com/github/lgooddatepicker/demo/TableEditorsDemo.java) showing this.

Comment: Why not do what the `TableEditorDemo` suggests and make use of the `DateTableEditor` (for both the renderer and editor)?  Seems like it solve your issues

Comment: Oh I misssed that, sorry I am going to check that, i'll tell you if it works

Comment: All I did for nothing xD
Thanks, I close the issue